# How to loop through each value of a specific column in Access

Tags: vba

I have a table with following information:

```
Destination        Currency Rate    Minutes     Amount Country
Pakistan           Mobile Uphone    USD 0.0150  12,500.00       
pakistan           Fixed Lahore     USD 0.0152  6,512.00        
Pakistan           Uphone Onnet     USD 0.1542  15,612.00       
India              Fixed Onnet      USD 0.1940  150,151.00      
India              Mumbai           USD 0.7462  1,161.00        
India              Mobile Reliance  USD 0.4798  16,431.00       
India              Mobile BSNL      USD 0.3655  64,311.00       
India              Bharti Mobile    USD 0.8450  43,434.00       
India              Idea Mobile      USD 0.1252  646,146.00
```

Using a form I am trying to find Country name in the country column. For this purpose I have a form with a button and the following code:

```
Private Sub cmdProceed_Click()

'Delcare variables
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim V1 As String
Dim V2 As String


'Initialize declared variables

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("FirstQuery")
V1 = rst.OpenRecordset.Fields("Destination")
V2 = "Pakistan"

'Perform the following things

rst.MoveFirst


Do While Not rst.EOF

rst.Edit

If (InStr(1, V1, V2)) > 0 Then

    rst.Fields("Country").Value = V2
Else
    rst.Fields("Country").Value = Nothing
End If

    rst.Update
    rst.MoveNext




Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

Me.Refresh

End Sub
```

When I run this code it will place "Pakistan" in "Country" column even against those records where text "Pakistan" does not exist. What I understand that my code is not changing value of Variable V1. Can anyone help me how can I get to a situation where if the text "Pakistan" exists in the "Destination" column, then value of "Country" column is equal to "Pakistan", else value of "Country" column is equal to nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Cause variable V1 is string, it will not automatic change value when you move next record in recordset.

You should put the code

```
V1 = rst.OpenRecordset.Fields("Destination")
```

inside the loop